# AS3 NetStream not indicating end of video

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I'm embedding an FLV file, and playing it via the `NetStream.appendBytes()` function. The video plays fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out when the video is finished playing.

According to [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d4d.html), I should be getting events with statuses like `NetStream.Play.Start`, `NetStream.Buffer.Empty`, `NetStream.Buffer.Full`, `NetStream.Buffer.Flush`, & `NetStream.Play.Stop` printed out from my below `statusHandler` function.

According to my understanding of [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onPlayStatus), I should be getting `NetStream.Play.Complete` printed out from my anonymous function attached to `ns.client.onPlayStatus`.

My output consists entirely of the following:

```
[trace] NetStatus: NetStream.Buffer.Full
[trace] NetStatus: NetStream.Buffer.Empty
```

The `Full` occurs when my video starts playing, and the `Empty` occurs when it's finished.

I'd like to have `NetStream.Play.Stop` or `NetStream.Play.Complete` fired. Here's my code, what have I done wrong?

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class Movie extends Sprite {

    [Embed(source="video.flv", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    private static const testFLV:Class;

    public function Movie():void {
        var video:Video = new Video(400, 300);
        addChildAt(video, 0);

        var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);

        var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

        var myClient:Object = new Object();
        ns.client = myClient;

        ns.client.onPlayStatus = function(info:Object):void {
            trace("onPlayStatus: " + info.code);
        };

        ns.client.onStatus = function(info:Object):void {
            trace("onStatus: " + info.code);
        };

        video.attachNetStream(ns);

        var vidBytes:ByteArray = new testFLV();
        ns.play(null);
        ns.appendBytes(vidBytes);

        ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusHandler);

    }

    private function statusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        trace("NetStatus: " + event.info.code);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why the -1? I've explained what I'm doing, the output I expect versus the output I get, and I've provided a SSCCE. How should I have asked this question differently?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Internal class  called Client.. like this...

```
 internal class Client
{
   public function onPlayStatus(info:Object):void
   {
    trace(info.code) // you should be able to catch the ( NetStream.Play.Complete)
   }

   public function onMetaData(info:Object):void
   {

   }
}
```

Then assign the  client property of the netstream object  like this...

```
    ns.client = new Client;
```

Hope that works. In princinple it should. A NetStream  Class is  a sealed Class so one can not add properties or methods to it at run time... if that is needed then subclass  it and define instance level methods / properties in that class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply B. Unfortunately, I'm not getting anything extra printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, embedding the FLV file and using NetStream.appendBytes is the same way as so-called "HTTP streaming".

I got this from the page [Monitoring NetStream Activity](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d11a09612fffaf8447-8000.html) where says:

1. In this way, NetStream doesn't have idea about many events of the playback, such as NetStream.Play.Start or NetStream.Play.Complete .
2. The player is supposed to synthesize, to dispatch I learn, the events.

I also learn form other forum that someone will use the NetStream.Buffer.Empty to as the complete event. But I think it also means the implicit pause for buffering, maybe for low bandwidth. I don't found a good way to distinguish.

Hope this helps. And it will be nice to have your update if any.

Comment: I ended up just using the `NetStream.Buffer.Empty` event to recognize the end of the video. Didn't feel good about that, but I couldn't figure out any other options.